# Documentation for python-software-properties

Tags: ubuntu

I'm writing some bash scripts to provision a Linode server of mine.  I am trying to find some documentation for the python-software-properties package.  Installing this package adds the ability to do something like the following:

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

Does anybody know where I can find documentation about python-software-properties, or know of the extra commands it adds?

Comment: You should ask this kind of question on http://askubuntu.com/. But in your case I guess it's useless, all available documentation is here http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python-software-properties (choose your distrib). And I've quickly take a look in the package, I don't find any docs...

Comment: He is programming and asking for a dependency documentation. It is the kind of question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"know of the extra commands it adds" - `dpkg -L python-software-properties` shows only the `add-apt-repository` in /usr/bin/, so it's the only command this package adds.

See `man add-apt-repository` for the documentation.